# An alternative proof for the units of $U_q(\mathfrak{sl}_2)$ using Ore extensions.

Tags: abstract-algebra, lie-algebras, quantum-groups

I would like to establish what the set of units are in the quantized enveloping algebra  $U_q(\mathfrak{sl}_2)$. First, I recall the definition of the quantized enveloping algebra- throughout the ground field will be taken to be $\mathbb{C}$ and $q\in \mathbb{C}$ is not a root of unity.

**Definition:** $U_q(\mathfrak{sl}_2)$ is the associative unital algebra generated by the four variables $E,F,K,K^{-1}$ subject to the defining relations:

\begin{align*}
KK^{-1}=&K^{-1}K=1\\
KEK^{-1}=q^2E, &\quad KFK^{-1}=q^{-2}F\\
[E,F]=&\frac{K-K^{-1}}{q-q^{-1}}.
\end{align*} 
I will often use the notation $U_q:=U_q(\mathfrak{sl}_2)$ for simplicity.
$U_q(\mathfrak{sl}_2)$  is a Hopf algebra, and can be viewed as a deformation of the enveloping algebra $U(\mathfrak{sl}_2)$- but both these things will not be too important for this particular problem, it will be the algebraic of structure of $U_q(\mathfrak{sl}_2)$ that plays a role here.

It is well known that $\{F^iK^{\ell}E^j:i,j\in \mathbb{N}_0, \ell \in \mathbb{Z}\}$ is a basis of $Uq(\mathfrak{sl}_2)$, it has no zero divisors, and that the units of $U_q(\mathfrak{sl}_2)$ are the elements of the form $\lambda K^{\ell}$ with $\lambda \in \mathbb{C}^{\times}$ and $\ell \in \mathbb{Z}$, one way this can be established is by establishing a formula for $E^i F^j$ in terms of the basis and one can impose an ordering on monomials in such a way that degree arguments can be used. See for example [This paper](http://hkumath.hku.hk/~imr/IMRPreprintSeries/2009/IMR2009-16.pdf) Lemma 2.1 on page 4. This is probably the preferred method for someone learning from Jantzen's book "Lectures on Quantum Groups", since there the desired formulas and gradings are discussed.

I would like to attempt a different proof of this result more in the spirit of Kassel's book "Quantum groups".

**Idea**

There it is proved that $U_q$ is an iterated Ore extension. To summarize: we set $A_0=\mathbb{C}[K,K^{-1}]$ and form the Ore extension $A_1=A_0[F,\alpha_1,0]$ where $\alpha_1$ is the automorphism of $A_0$ determined by $\alpha_1(K)=q^2K$. It turns out that $A_1$ is the algebra generated by $F,K,K^{-1}$ subject to the relation $FK=q^2KF$.One can then form the Ore extension $A_2=A_1[E,\alpha_2,\delta]$ where $\alpha_2$ is determined by $\alpha_2(F^jK^{\ell})=q^{-2\ell}F^j K^{\ell}$ and $\delta$ is an $\alpha_2$ derivation of $A_1$ with $\delta(K)=\frac{K-K^{-1}}{q-q^{-1}}$. It is not too difficult to see that $A_2\cong U_q(\mathfrak{sl}_2).$

My idea is that it should be easier to determine what the units are if we view $U_q$ as the Ore extension $A_2$. Specifically, as a set $A_2=A_1[E,\alpha_2,\delta]$ is just $A_1[E]$ (polynomials in one indeterminate), with a different algebra structure, $A_2$ has no zero divisors and shares the nice property of behaving well with respect to degrees: If $P$ and $Q$ are in $A_2$, then $\deg(PQ)=\deg(P)+\deg(Q)$. Thus if $P$ is a unit in $A_2$ with inverse $Q$, then from this we can deduce that $P$ must belong to $A_1$. We can actually be more specific: If $P=\sum_{i=0}^n a_i E^i,\enspace Q=\sum_{i=0}^m b_iE^i$ then $PQ=\sum_{i=0}^{n+m}c_i E^i$ where:
$$c_i=\sum_{p=0}^i a_p \sum_{k=0}^p S_{p,k}(b_{i-p+k}) $$
where $S_{n,k}$ is the linear endomorphism of $A_1$ defined as the sum of all $n \choose k$ compositions of $k$ copies of $\delta$ and of $n-k$ copies of $\alpha_2$ (see Kassel Corollary I.7.4).

From this we get that $a_0$ must be a unit in $A_1$. Thus we have reduced the argument to finding the units of $A_1=A_0[F,\alpha_1,0]$, but by an identical argument we can conclude that the units of $A_1$ are the units of $A_0$, i.e the units of $\mathbb{C}[K,K^{-1}]$, which are precisely the elements of the form $\lambda K^{\ell}$ with $\ell\in \mathbb{Z}$ and $\lambda$ a nonzero scalar (this is not difficult to prove but I omit it here).

**Closing Thoughts** This is my first exposure to Ore extensions, but I am fairly certain I have applied the theory correctly. Nonetheless, I would appreciate a second look, or any comments on the work.

Comment: The quantum group has nothing to do with this: just consider an Ore extension of a domain (with an automorphism and a derivation) and find its units.

Comment: Hi Mariano, I deduced this when doing the proof- that it should always go through this way with Ore extensions of a domain- I just had never seen Ore extensions before. It seems they preserve many of the really nice properties of polynomial rings- such as the one here. In this specific case I am using the result to find all the grouplike elements of $U_q$- which is why my focus was on on this quantum group. Thank you for the comment!